# why ThreadPool is in multiproceesing module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

or

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
```

---

Why there is no something like

```
from threading.pool import Pool
```

Comment: Because it gives threading a muliprocessing-like interface.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not documented, we can only guess or investigate whole codebase of ThreadPool :)